# How to find the number of solution pairs for this equation?

Tags: roots

**Question**: Consider the equation $(1+a+b)^2=3(1+a^2+b^2)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. How many solution pair(s), ($a$,$b$), are possible for this equation?

**My attempt**:

$(1+a+b)^2=3(1+a^2+b^2)$

=>$1+a^2+b^2+2(a+ab+b)=3+3a^2+3b^2$

=>$1+a^2+b^2+2a+2ab+2b=3+3a^2+3b^2$

=>$2a+2ab+2b=2+2a^2+2b^2$

=>$2(a+ab+b)=2(1+a^2+b^2)$

=>$a+ab+b=1+a^2+b^2$

=>$a-ab+b-1=a^2+b^2-2ab$

=>$-a(b-1)+1(b-1)=(a-b)^2$

=>$(b-1)(1-a)=(a-b)^2$

I have simplified the given equation to this point. I cannot understand how to proceed. I would be grateful for any help i receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, dxiv showed you a standard solution, but you have a good result there. Let $x=1-a$ and $y=b-1$ then $xy=(x+y)^2$ or $-xy=x^2+y^2$. Notice that $$2|x||y| \le x^2+y^2=-xy \le |x||y|,$$which gives you $|x||y| \le 0$. This is possible only when $|x||y|=0$.

Comment: How did you get $2|x||y|≤x^2+y^2=−xy≤|x||y|$?

Comment: $-xy \le |x||y|$ is clear. I think you have a little problem with $2|x||y| \le x^2+y^2$. Notice that $$(|x|-|y|)^2 \ge 0 \Longrightarrow  |x|^2+|y|^2 \ge 2|x| |y|. $$

Comment: Why is  $|x||y|≤0$?

Comment: Well, that argument gives $$2|x||y| \le ... \le |x||y|.$$This means $2|x||y| \le |x||y|$ or $|x||y| \le 0$

Comment: If $|x||y|≤0$, then either $|x|=0$ or $|y|=0$ or both $|x|=|y|=0$. So should not that give more than 1 solution pair?

Comment: $x=0$ gives $y=0$ and vice versa.

Comment: $y$ is not necessarily equal to $0$. It may have any value.

Comment: If $x=0$, then $x^2+y^2=-xy$ gives $y=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   after expanding and collecting, the equation can be written as:
$$a^2 - a b - a + b^2 - b + 1 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; a^2 - (b+1)\,a + b^2-b+1=0$$

Considering it as a quadratic in $\,a\,$, its discriminant is:

$$
\Delta=(b+1)^2-4(b^2-b+1)=-3b^2+6b-3=-3(b-1)^2
$$

For the quadratic to have real roots the discriminant must be non-negative, so $\;\cdots$

Comment: The quadratic equation in $a$ has two complex roots since the discriminant is negative. We can similarly rearrange the same equation and regard it as a quadratic equation in $b$ and from it we obtain two complex values of b and thus there are two solution pairs $(a,b)$ possible. Right?

Comment: @MrAP The question asks for *real* roots. The only case where $\Delta$ is *not* negative is for $b=1$ when $\Delta=0$, therefore $b=1$, and in that case the equation reduces to $a^2-2a+1=0$.